# I am trying to do a visual basic console application and The error I get is:Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code. I get error in Chk_regular.Checked = dr("regular_yn").ToString). Please help me with what should I replace in it

```
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Try
        openNewInstanceOfConnection()
        cmd.Connection = connection
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT freeze_by_days,regular_yn,offal_yn,trim_yn,cull_yn,grind_yn,haccp_level,lot_needed_yn,active_yn FROM tbl_products WHERE pdt_code = @pdt"
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pdt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProdCode.Text
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read
                txt_freeze.Text = dr("freeze_by_days").ToString
                txt_haccpLvl.Text = dr("haccp_level").ToString
                Chk_regular.Checked = dr("regular_yn").ToString
                Chk_offal.Checked = dr("offal_yn").ToString
                Chk_trim.Checked = dr("trim_yn").ToString
                Chk_cull.Checked = dr("cull_yn").ToString
                Chk_grind.Checked = dr("grind_yn").ToString
                Chk_lotNeed.Checked = dr("lot_needed_yn").ToString
                Chk_active.Checked = dr("active_yn").ToString
```

Comment: What data type are those columns within SQL?

Comment: What value are you getting from those YN fields?

Comment: `Checked` is a boolean property.  Using `ToString` on a db field returns a string not a boolean

Comment: the data types are in bit @james

Comment: You should use [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) to let Visual Studio show you some problems and suggest solutions.

Comment: `Chk_regular.Checked = dr.GetBoolean("regular_yn")`  There are a myriad of wonderful things you can learn with a little curiosity about the things Intellisense` offers

Comment: After using this Chk_regular.Checked = dr.GetBoolean("regular_yn") i get error like Conversion from string "regular_yn" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: Sorry, the typed Get???? methods require the column number, so `rdr.GetBoolean(rdr.GetOrdinal("checked_yn"))`. or `rdr.GetBoolean(1)` since checked_yn is the second column specified in the query

Answer (score 0):

Checked Property accepts Boolean values . Use Convert.ToBool function to parse the value and assign it to the Checked property